# how to Check Float value Is Null Or not?

Tags: android, floating-point

I have some EditText which is of "numberDecimal", and One Button. When user clicks on button, data goes to Database. So how to check EditText is empty or not. I am getting error when I try to parse the EditText.

Comment: **`TextUtils.isEmpty(editText.getText().toString().trim());`**

Answer (score 0):

To check an edittext is empty:

```
EditText ed = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ed);
age = ed.getText().toString();
if (age.matches("")) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}
```

You can also use **equals()** instead of **matches()**

Comment: Thx, But I have Float Value. Complainer does not able to pars 0 value

Comment: yes it is converting float to string through toSting() method